# Gevent worker is blocked by SQLAlchemy's query

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, gevent

I am running a Flask app using gunicorn with only 1 gevent worker and using MySQL database via SQLAlchemy with mysql-connector and executing a long-time query.

When issuing two API calls simultaneously, the worker is blocked or killed due to the timeout of the first query until the database responds and the second API call is handled.

The package versions are: (by the way, the latest versions still get the same result)

```
flask = "2.0.3"
sqlalchemy = "1.4.39"
mysql-connector-python = "8.0.29"
gunicorn = "20.1.0"
gevent = "22.10.2"
```

Here's the main.py:

```py
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, scoped_session, sessionmaker


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    print("!!!! GET REQUEST !!!!")

    db_url = "mysql+mysqlconnector://username:password@host:3306/db_name"

    engine = create_engine(db_url)

    session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session: Session = scoped_session(session_maker)

    sql_string = """
        select *
        from big_table
        inner join another_big_table
        group by big_table.id;
    """

    result = session.execute(sql_string)
    result = dict(result.fetchall())

    session.close()

    print(result)
    print("!!!! FINISH REQUEST !!!!")

    return ""
```

The command to start the Flask server:

```
gunicorn -k gevent -w 1 -b 127.0.0.1:11111 main:app
```

The command to invoke api:

```
curl localhost:11111
```